# How to connect / "glue"/ combine many Bitmap to one?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have many **raster** files, and know their proportions in the final image. These files are completely different sizes and resolution (many very large).

How can I make them a **bitmap** file?

Resolution of the final **bitmap**  must be equal to the minimum resolution of the incoming **bitmap**.

I tried to do so, but I could not get what I want:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            Point location = new Point(temp[i].Propx* width * 300/ 25.4, temp[i].Propy*height* 300/ 25.4);
            Size size = new Size(temp[i].Propwidth*width * 300/ 25.4, temp[i].Propheight*300* height/ 25.4);
            Rect rect = new Rect(location, size);
            drawingContext.DrawImage(tempBS[i], rect);
        }
        drawingContext.Close();
        Size finalSize = new Size(300*width/25.4, 300*height/25.4);
        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                         (int) finalSize.Width,(int) finalSize.Height,
                          300d, 300d, 
                          PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
       bmp.Render(drawingVisual);

       using (var fs = File.OpenWrite("D:\\1.jpg"))
        {
            var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 100 };
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
            encoder.Save(fs);
        }
```

where width and height it's final size bitmap in mm. Propwidth - percentage of the final bitmap (0 to 1). But I can only see part of the bitmap.

I will explain to the simple example that I want to learn. Let's say we have two bitmap file:

1. 3000 to 4000 pixels with a resolution of 250 dpi. It takes 0.5 times the width of the final image on the left.
2. 1000 by 1000 pixels with a resolution of 350 dpi. 0.5 width of the resulting image on the right.

It is necessary to obtain a bitmap, not less known dimensions in mm (or inches, let 6х16 inches) and with the highest possible resolution and quality. Min result resolution it's 100dpi.

For this example, the result should be: size 2000х750, resolutoin 100dpi

Comment: is this question related to c#/wpf? image magick has a command line to do this

Comment: What have you tried so far, I see this is a C# question can you show where you are in trying to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, it is the wpf application. Used Net 3.5

Comment: I tried to create a RenderTargetBitmap, and render DrawingVisual. But RenderTargetBitmap can create a bitmap with the system only resolution (96d)

Comment: @Mike K. I added a last attempt in question